# Mixpanel – how do I carry guest's property to user's property?

Tags: mixpanel

I'm new to Mixpanel, and I'm tracking a platform website. Right now I'm planning to record the first product viewed by a guest (not yet a user)

```
if (_.isEmpty(this.user)) {
  mixpanel.identify(mixpanel.get_distinct_id())
}
else {
  mixpanel.identify(this.user.id)
}
mixpanel.people.set_once({
  'First product viewed': this.product.name
})
```

But for some reason, when the guest becomes a user, their profile's property doesn't contain this info anymore.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

According to mixpanel's best practices, you shouldn't Identify a user until they sign up or sign in, so in theory you really couldn't create a People profile or set a people property until after the user signs up. I think you'd need to store that first-product-viewed value somehow so that you can set it as a people property after the user has signed up.